# lfs gcc-7.3.0 -Pass 2 error C cannot create executables

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch

I am currently trying to make my first linux from scratch(lfs) build, I need to make the GCC-7.3.0 - pass 2 but the output of the ../configure step of the book(Chapter 5.10) give me an error. All the previous steps are working,binutils pass 2 seem to worked, gcc and g++ are working. From my readings ive learn that I needed to delete the 1st pass binutils and gcc sources, so I did it in the logical order. Ive try to read the config.log file but i cannot find the solution, some lines seem suspicious like that gcc cannot resolve the '-V' and 'qversion' cli arguments and the &5 argument. This is the content of the config.log file generated :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --prefix=/tools --with-local-prefix=/tools --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/in
clude --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap --disab
le-libgomp

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = debian
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.9.0-4-amd64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23)

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /tools/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2304: checking build system type
configure:2318: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2365: checking host system type
configure:2378: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2398: checking target system type
configure:2411: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2465: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2533: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2544: checking whether ln works
configure:2566: result: yes
configure:2570: checking whether ln -s works
configure:2574: result: yes
configure:2581: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2645: result: /bin/sed
configure:2654: checking for gawk
configure:2670: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2681: result: gawk
configure:3175: checking for libatomic support
configure:3185: result: yes
configure:3194: checking for libcilkrts support
configure:3204: result: yes
configure:3232: checking for libitm support
configure:3242: result: yes
configure:3251: checking for libsanitizer support
configure:3261: result: yes
configure:3270: checking for libvtv support
configure:3280: result: yes
configure:3290: checking for libmpx support
configure:3300: result: yes
configure:3309: checking for libhsail-rt support
configure:3321: result: yes
configure:4038: checking for gcc
configure:4065: result: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
configure:4294: checking for C compiler version
configure:4303: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc --version >&5
x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4314: $? = 0
configure:4303: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --target=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu --prefix=/tools --with-glibc-version=2.11 --with-sysroot=/mnt/lfs --with-newlib --without-headers --with-local-prefix=/tools --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-multilib --disable-decimal-float --disable-threads --disable-libatomic --disable-libgomp --disable-libmpx --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libvtv --disable-libstdcxx --enable-languages=c,c++
Thread model: single
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC) 
configure:4314: $? = 0
configure:4303: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -V >&5
x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4314: $? = 1
configure:4303: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -qversion >&5
x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4314: $? = 1
configure:4334: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:4356: x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/mnt/lfs/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu/7.3.0/libgcc.a: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:4360: $? = 1
configure:4397: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4403: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-7.3.0/build':
configure:4407: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AR_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AR_set=set
ac_cv_env_AR_value=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ar
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_AS_set=
ac_cv_env_AS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-g++
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_set=
ac_cv_env_DLLTOOL_value=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GCC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_GOC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LD_set=
ac_cv_env_LD_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_set=
ac_cv_env_LIPO_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_NM_set=
ac_cv_env_NM_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCOPY_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJDUMP_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_set=set
ac_cv_env_RANLIB_value=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ranlib
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_READELF_set=
ac_cv_env_READELF_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_set=
ac_cv_env_STRIP_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDMC_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_FOR_TARGET_value=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_set=
ac_cv_env_WINDRES_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_build_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_host_configargs_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_set=
ac_cv_env_target_configargs_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_SED=/bin/sed
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
ac_cv_target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
acx_cv_prog_LN=ln

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ar'
AR_FOR_BUILD='$(AR)'
AR_FOR_TARGET=''
AS=''
AS_FOR_BUILD='$(AS)'
AS_FOR_TARGET=''
AWK='gawk'
BISON=''
BUILD_CONFIG=''
CC='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc'
CC_FOR_BUILD='$(CC)'
CC_FOR_TARGET=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_AS_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_LD_FOR_TARGET=''
COMPILER_NM_FOR_TARGET=''
CONFIGURE_GDB_TK=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-g++'
CXXFLAGS=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
CXX_FOR_BUILD='$(CXX)'
CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
DEBUG_PREFIX_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLLTOOL_FOR_BUILD='$(DLLTOOL)'
DLLTOOL_FOR_TARGET=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPECT=''
FLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
FLEX=''
GCC_FOR_TARGET=''
GCC_SHLIB_SUBDIR=''
GDB_TK=''
GFORTRAN_FOR_BUILD='$(GFORTRAN)'
GFORTRAN_FOR_TARGET=''
GNATBIND=''
GNATMAKE=''
GOC_FOR_BUILD='$(GOC)'
GOC_FOR_TARGET=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_GDB_TK=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=''
LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
LD_FOR_BUILD='$(LD)'
LD_FOR_TARGET=''
LEX=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO=''
LIPO_FOR_TARGET=''
LN='ln'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
M4=''
MAINT=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE=''
MAKEINFO=''
NM=''
NM_FOR_BUILD='$(NM)'
NM_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJCOPY_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJDUMP_FOR_TARGET=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ranlib'
RANLIB_FOR_BUILD='$(RANLIB)'
RANLIB_FOR_TARGET=''
RAW_CXX_FOR_TARGET=''
READELF=''
READELF_FOR_TARGET=''
RPATH_ENVVAR=''
RUNTEST=''
SED='/bin/sed'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
STRIP=''
STRIP_FOR_TARGET=''
SYSROOT_CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=''
TOPLEVEL_CONFIGURE_ARGUMENTS='../configure --prefix=/tools --with-local-prefix=/tools --with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-multilib --disable-bootstrap --disable-libgomp'
WINDMC=''
WINDMC_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDMC)'
WINDMC_FOR_TARGET=''
WINDRES=''
WINDRES_FOR_BUILD='$(WINDRES)'
WINDRES_FOR_TARGET=''
YACC=''
ac_ct_CC='x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_configargs=''
build_configdirs='build-libiberty build-libcpp build-texinfo build-flex build-bison build-m4 build-fixincludes'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_libsubdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_subdir='build-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_tooldir=''
build_vendor='pc'
compare_exclusions=''
configdirs='intl libiberty opcodes bfd readline tcl tk itcl libgui zlib libbacktrace libcpp libdecnumber gmp mpfr mpc isl libelf libiconv texinfo flex bison binutils gas ld fixincludes gcc cgen sid sim gdb gprof etc expect dejagnu m4 utils guile fastjar gnattools libcc1 gotools'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
do_compare=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_host_libiberty_configure_flags=''
extra_host_zlib_configure_flags=''
extra_isl_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_liboffloadmic_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_configure_flags=''
extra_linker_plugin_flags=''
extra_mpc_gmp_configure_flags=''
extra_mpc_mpfr_configure_flags=''
extra_mpfr_configure_flags=''
get_gcc_base_ver=''
gmpinc=''
gmplibs=''
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_configargs=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_shared=''
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
islinc=''
isllibs=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
poststage1_ldflags=''
poststage1_libs=''
prefix='/tools'
program_transform_name='s,y,y,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stage1_cflags=''
stage1_checking=''
stage1_languages=''
stage1_ldflags=''
stage1_libs=''
stage2_werror_flag=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_alias=''
target_configargs=''
target_configdirs='target-libgcc target-libbacktrace target-libgloss target-newlib target-libgomp target-libcilkrts target-liboffloadmic target-libhsail-rt target-libatomic target-libitm target-libstdc++-v3 target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libmpx target-libssp target-libquadmath target-libgfortran target-libffi target-libobjc target-libada target-libgo target-rda'
target_cpu='x86_64'
target_noncanonical='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_os='linux-gnu'
target_subdir='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
target_vendor='pc'
tooldir=''

## ------------------- ##
## File substitutions. ##
## ------------------- ##

alphaieee_frag=''
host_makefile_frag='/dev/null'
ospace_frag=''
serialization_dependencies=''
target_makefile_frag=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 77
```

What could be the issue and what can i do to fix this ? Ive already make a lot of searching for the answer and ive found nothing so perhaps someone here can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow (SO), SO is for code related questions, questions around Linux system have to be asked on superuser or serverfault

Comment: Oh sorry about that, i didn't know, is it possible to move the current topic on superuser ?Thanks.